# INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore

Tags: python, tensorflow

tf 2.0

Hello, I am relatively new to tensorflow and want to use pre-trained models for object detection from the tensorflow model zoo.

but when I try to load the model ( via f.saved_model.load but also when I use the pre-built load_model function from the official tensorflow object detection API, I always get the following error message:

INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUFnt.png)

iOS 10.15.2
TF 2.0
anaconda 3
python 3.7.6// also tried with 3.6
cpu

installed nomkl 3.0

downloaded the 
object detection API 
included all required packages as pillow etc.

model from the tf model zoo: ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28 3

Loading keras models (.h5) runs perfectly